# Interfaces implementation visibility

Tags: interfaces

I have this interface:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
interface EventsInterface 
{
   function removeValueFromArray(uint _userId, uint[] array) external 
   returns(uint[]);
}
```

And this contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./EventsInterface.sol";

contract EventsImpl is EventsInterface {

    function removeValueFromArray(uint _userId, uint[] _array) internal returns(uint[]) {

    uint[] storage auxArray;

    for (uint i = 0; i < _array.length; i++){
        if(_array[i] != _userId)
            auxArray.push(_array[i]);
    }

    return auxArray;
}
}
```

When I try to deploy de contract. Remix report me a error:

> This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created.

Changing to public the Impl function:

```
function removeValueFromArray(uint _userId, uint[] _array) public returns(uint[]) {

    uint[] storage auxArray;

    for (uint i = 0; i < _array.length; i++){
        if(_array[i] != _userId)
            auxArray.push(_array[i]);
    }

    return auxArray;
}
```

I get the following error

> TypeError: Function overload clash during conversion to external types for arguments

To fix the issue I set to public bouth functions (Interface/Implementation) and works. But I getting one warning that tell me that interface function must be external and not public

Comment: So listen to the warning - interface functions must be `external`, hence their implementation (in a contract) must be `external` too.

Comment: @goodvibration I believe the restriction of interface functions being external-only is from 0.5.0, but this person is using 0.4.24?

Comment: It sounds like you fixed the errors already and are just getting a warning that you can choose to follow or ignore. What is the question right now?

Comment: @RoscoKalis the question evolve. And the problem is that I cant fix the error and the warning at the same time. First I have a error, i solve but now I have a warning. Is there a way to fix this error/warning??

Comment: @AnAllergyToAnalogy: No, it's in 0.4.x as well (and probably in every version back to the initial one).

Comment: So if you make both the function in the interface and the implementation external, it still doesn't work?

Comment: If I put bouth external(the interface and the implementation). The contract deploy but i can´t call the function internally in the same contract. So the external(interface) public(implementation) is the option that I need. I have to ignore the warning

Comment: @goodvibration you're right in 0.4.x it gave a warning but would still compile, whereas in 0.5.x it will actually give a TypeError. Which is not to say your advice was bad or incorrect, just that in version 0.4.x it was recommended (ie, _should_) rather than mandatory (ie, _must_). Pointless semantics, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you actually need this function to be internal, you could use just inheritance instead of interface:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract EventsInterface 
{
   function removeValueFromArray(uint _userId, uint[] memory _array) internal returns(uint[] memory);
}

contract EventsImpl is EventsInterface {
    uint[] baseArray;

    function removeValueFromArray(uint _userId, uint[] memory _array) internal returns(uint[] memory) {
        uint[] storage auxArray = baseArray;

        for (uint i = 0; i < _array.length; i++){
            if(_array[i] != _userId)
                auxArray.push(_array[i]);
        }

        return auxArray;
    }
}
```

This contract will compile with version 0.4.24 and with version 0.5.4, too.

Note that you must set the location of a few variables (namely the original array and the returned uint[]).